# How to memoize an api response in clojure?

Tags: clojure, memoization

I want to `memoize` a function return that a function makes a http request  to an API.

I'm unable to do it.

```
(defn _get_userid 
  [id cid]   
  (p1.nms2/get_uerid id cid))

(def get_userid   
  (memo/ttl _get_userid 
            {} 
            :ttl/threshold p1.constant/ttl-millisecs))
```

Comment: (p1.nms2/get_uerid id cid)  is a function that will call an api

Comment: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memoize

Comment: Your usage of the memoize library's `ttl` function appears correct https://github.com/clojure/core.memoize/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/memoize.clj#L432 could you add the usage, actual output, and expected output to your question?

Comment: Please add the require/depency, that brings in `memo`.  Also "I'm unable to do it." is not giving any hints, what is going wrong.  Please add a clear statement of the problem you are facing.

Comment: i have 2 args to the memoize functions , out of 2 , 1 is actually used and the other is for logging , 1 which is actually used is  same where as the one which is not used keeps changing , i need to get both the argument but need to memoize based on only one ? .

Comment: In your example both of your arguments are passed to the `p1.nms2/get_uerid` function, so a memoize there doesn't really make sense if you want different cid's to be cached under the same memoized function. Almost definitely the answer here is to create another function that only takes the parameter you care about and then memoize that. However it would be much more clear if you updated your question with your usage, your expected output, and your actual output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your 2nd parameter is like a context (for logging), you can use a dynamic var so you don't need to pass it as an extra argument to your memoized function.

```clj
(def ^:dynamic *cid* nil)

(def get-userid
  (memoize
   (fn [id]
     {:input   id
      :context *cid*
      :output  (inc id)})))

(binding [*cid* "what"]
  (get-userid 1))
;; => {:input 1, :context "what", :output 2}

(binding [*cid* "when"]
  (get-userid 1))
;; => {:input 1, :context "what", :output 2}

(binding [*cid* "why"]
  (get-userid 2))
;; => {:input 2, :context "why", :output 3}
```